# Conversion from PNG to EPS

Tags: graphics, images, postscript, png

I would like to convert PNG images/graphs to EPS without losing even a bit on resolution. All the commands I tried (`potrace`, `autotrace`, `convert`, `gimp`) decrease the resolution quality.

Comment: When you say "conversion to EPS", do you actually want to vectorize the image, or do you just want to wrap the PNG image into a EPS file?

Comment: I want to vectorize the image

Comment: What do you mean by "losing a bit"? How do you want to compare the output **vector** graphics data with the original PNG? Do you render the vector graphics? If so with what, at what resolution compared to the PNG and with what kind of anti-aliasing?

Comment: Yes I understand about "without losing even a bit on resolution". I am sorry, I just meant the best possible eps image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some people have had success with [png2eps](https://github.com/rkh/papers/blob/master/swt/pics/png2eps).

Remember that whatever system you use to convert PNG to EPS it will be a tradeoff between image quality and file size.  PNG is a compressed bitmap format while EPS is uncompressed vector graphics - the two formats couldn't be more different.

There is no resolution in a vector image until you attempt to convert it to a bitmap, or display it (a vector image is converted to bitmap for printing or displaying on a monitor). Unfortunately, converting "*without losing even a bit on resolution*" doesn't make sense in this instance.

Also note that the resulting EPS file will be much larger than the PNG input.

Comment: Yes I understand about "without losing even a bit on resolution". I am sorry, I just meant the best possible eps image.